# Error: Malformed array literal, trying to pass in an array into TEXT[] column

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, arrays, postgresql

So I have an array that has been created in Node.JS by pushing elements to an array, that I'm then trying to set to a PostgreSQL Text[] column. So it's something like this:

```
var hours = []
for (x of hourStrings) {
  hours.push(x) // Here, x is something like {"2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00","2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00"},{},{"2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00","2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00"}
}
```

My element that I'm trying to put into a Postgres column looks like this:

```
{{"2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00","2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00"},{},{"2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00","2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00"},{"2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00","2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00"},{"2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00","2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00"},{"2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00","2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00"},{"2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00","2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00"}}
```

and the error I'm getting is this:

```
error: malformed array literal: "{{"2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00","2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00"},{},{"2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00","2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00"},{"2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00","2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00"},{"2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00","2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00"},{"2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00","2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00"},{"2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00","2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00"}}"
```

I'm querying with this:

```
const client = await pool.connect()
await client.query(`INSERT INTO tableName (hoursColumn) VALUES($1) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`, [hours]);
```

I don't see where the error is in the object. Not sure how to fix this, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the `postgres query` and also the js code where you're using that query

Answer (score 1):

For this instead of a for loop I used foreach and it seemed to work for me! I also changed up hourStrings.

```
let hourStrings = ["2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00","2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00","2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00","2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00","2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00","2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00","2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00","2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00","2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00","2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00","2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00","2022-05-07T12:00:00+01:00 - 2022-05-07T16:00:00+01:00"]

let  hours = []

hourStrings.forEach(element => {
    hours.push(element)
});


console.log(hours)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't really change up the format. See my comment on Grzegorz's post. That's the format the post to the table needs to contain. It's dynamically populated which is why the subarrays may be multidimensional.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in empty element **{}** you have in text.

Additionally each element of the array should have the same dimension

Comment: What if they can't have the same dimension? I need it to be structured something like: {{}, {"item 1"}, {"item 1", "item 2"}, {"item 1"} etc etc }. This array is dynamically updated, so there's no predictability in the length of the sub-arrays.

Comment: Also as a side note, I've tried inserting "", "N/A", and {"N/A"} instead of {}.

Comment: You can store JSON object

Comment: And you should store {"","'} instead of {}

Comment: If the sub-arrays can have 1,2,3...+ elements and not necessarily the same as the other sub arrays, I can't hardcode an empty array though, right? If I want to store as a JSON object, that's the JSONb type right?

Comment: from [PostgreSQL Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html)
Multidimensional arrays must have matching extents for each dimension.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244582/discussion-between-grzegorz-kraska-and-nickcoding2).